# GRUB won't boot after Ubuntu disk dies

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have a system with two internal drives. The Master drive is win7, and I installed Ubuntu on a partition on the other drive for test purposes.

I modified the bootloader sequence to put the Win7 disk at the top.

All good.

The disk that contained Ubuntu is now toast. It is not recoverable. Since there is only Ubuntu on it, I don't really care, and the disk is in the trash.

However, the astuste reader will now know that I cannot boot at all, because GRUB can no longer see the disk that has Ubuntu on it. I get the "grub rescue" prompt.

What to do?

(please do not tell me to boot Ubuntu from a CD or a flash disk or the inoperable old disk since none of these options are immediately available to me. I have no idea what the Linux names of the disks are either)

Answer (score 0):

i think your grub is installed on your Ubuntu disk. And as you have no plans to reinstall Ubuntu i suggest you to use windows bootloader use windows rescue disk or windows installation disk and run "fixmbr" or "bootrec /firmbr" or similar command to fix your boot record

Answer (score 0):

You can simply repair Ubuntu Grub using [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) download the original ISO file form [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) restore it USB Using UNetbootin.then reboot and repair the Grub.